# TypeScript issue: Cannot resolve definitions for module 'numeral'

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I have this file: `numberUrils.ts` which contains this:

```js
import numeral from 'numeral';

export const formatNumber = (number) => numeral(number).format('0,0a');
```

Now my IDE complains about this:
[image]

And its not just that package I import, a few others too.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Do I have something wrongly configured?

Comment: Well, have you installed the @types/numeral package?

Comment: I dont get why I need to install that. For a non typescript project I never needed that

Comment: Yeah, typescript is a bit different here. Basically, if a package does not come with it's own type definitions (e.g. is written in typescript), there may be community provided type definitions in the `@types` organisation. You can read more about that here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#what-are-declaration-files-and-how-do-i-get-them

Comment: there are ways to consume JavaScript packages without type declarations but if one is available under @types, that's going to be the right thing to use 99.9% of the time.